# How to keep a material ui select specific menu item selected?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using react with material ui . When using select component ,  I want to keep a specific menu item keep selected initially.
For example  here I want `<MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>` to be default selected . Passing `selected={true}` prop not working.

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
    <InputLabel id="demo-controlled-open-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
    <Select
      labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
      id="demo-controlled-open-select"
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      onOpen={handleOpen}
      value={age}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={20} selected={true}>Twenty</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
```

Comment: Initialize your age state with default selected value, for e.g, ```const [age, setAge]  = useState(30)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `defaultValue` prop of [Select](https://material-ui.com/api/select/) component, if you're not controlling the component.

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
<InputLabel id="demo-controlled-open-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
<Select
  labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
  id="demo-controlled-open-select"
  open={open}
  onClose={handleClose}
  onOpen={handleOpen}
  defaultValue={20}
  onChange={handleChange}
>
  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

For controlled component initialize your state variable (age in your case) with a default value.

Comment: How can we highlight the selected menu-item, like making it's font weight bold or so?